# WPF - Binding a datagrid to datatable, autogenerated columns, booleans aren't marked as checked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, datagrid

I have a wpf user control with a datagrid that is bound to data table.  Columns are autogenerated.  For some reason, the boolean values that are bound are not showing as checked.  The text columns I have are showing up correctly.  Here is the code I have:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data.DefaultView}" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    CanUserAddRows="False" 
    CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
    CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
    CanUserSortColumns="False" 
    CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
    CanUserResizeRows="True" 
    />
```

Code in View-Model:

```
    public void SetupDataTable()
    {
        this.Data = new DataTable();

        var column = this.Data.Columns.Add("#", typeof(int));
        column.ReadOnly = true;
        column = this.Data.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
        column.ReadOnly = true;
        column = this.Data.Columns.Add(this.CurrentReliefDevice.ToString(), typeof(bool));
        column.ReadOnly = true;

        foreach (var reliefDevice in this.OtherReliefDevices)
        {
            this.Data.Columns.Add(reliefDevice.ToString(), typeof(bool));
        }

        foreach (var pipeItem in this.PipeItems)
        {
            var dataRow = this.Data.NewRow();

            dataRow[0] = pipeItem.PipeItemNumber;
            dataRow[1] = pipeItem.PipeItemType?.ShortName;
            dataRow[2] = true;

            var array = this.OtherReliefDevices.ToArray();
            for (var i = 0; i < array.Count(); i++)
            {
                dataRow[i + 3] = pipeItem.AssociatedReliefDevices.Contains(array[i]);
            }

            this.Data.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }

        this.Data.AcceptChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Specifically, what I'm seeing is that the dataRow[2] isn't showing up as checked in the grid even though it's getting set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was unrelated to the bindings.  My column headers, which are available at runtime, have periods "." in them.  This is apparently an issue that breaks the column header.  When I remove the period, it works just fine.